# Drupal 7 ubercart roles assignment ineffectual

Tags: users

Nothing happens when I test in the sandbox with paypal standards payment and everything set up through ubercart for recurring subscriptions and feature added role assignment, when I edit product subscription roles assign on purchase to go to certain role and the payment goes through the sandbox I get redirected back to site but the role has not changed to reflect the purchase. What am I missing here?

Comment: After much checking I think I found the culprit which is in paypal sandbox itself as noticed all testing orders were "payment pending" so will try live payments and see if the roles assign works.

Answer (score 0):

In case this happens to anyone else, when using the sandbox if configured so output becomes payment pending, role assignments will logically not work.

You just need to login to your developer paypal site and click on the test account you are using in settings and switch payment review to off.